# Loading translation data under Globalize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize

Rails applications using Globalize gem generate a database table for a givenmodel's translations named `givenmodel_translations` with each attribute defined in the givenmodel.rb file.

However starting with a pre-existing data where translation data needs to be created in the translations table - say from a CSV file - there is no railsish way of calling the table. *note: this model has also image size validations and works with slugs to find objects*  One cannot call from the console

```
GivenmodelTranslation.create( :locale => row[0], :title => row[1] [...] )
```

How can such data be populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globalize creates namespaced translation models:

```
Givenmodel::Translation
```

However I haven't seen it documented so it could change in the next versions.